# DPDK-PDUMP for SRIOV interfaces

Tags: dpdk

DPDK pdump has limitation that it is unable to capture over SRIOV interface, because of PDUMP running as a secondary application. As a result, DPDK packets are not captured. When DPDK is planning to remove such restriction?

Expectation - Remove the DPDK pdump limitation for SRIOV.